# vSphere HA: Automatic shutdown of VMs to free up resources

Tags: vmware-vsphere, high-availability, vmware-vcenter

Assume we have 2 ESXi hosts with these machines:

```
ESX1: A1, B1, C1, D1
ESX2: A2, B2, C2, D2
```

A & B VMs are the most important VMs for us. 
We have configured vSphere HA in a test environment. The two hosts have been included in an HA Cluster. By using VM override settings, the restart priority of C & D machines has been set to "never".

Now consider this situtation: 
ESX1 fails, and A1 and B1 are automatically started on the ESX2.

The question now:
How can I configure vSphere to automatically shutdown C2 and D2 VMs if we have lack of resources on ESX2?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't make such rule out of the box, but you can configure your HA to poweroff C1, D1. That would save you some resources.

You should have enough memory to support a fail-over, how you can migrate to make a maintenance in exemple ? If you fall into the balloon memory, that mean you have to invest for RAM please.

Comment: Why C1 & D1? We have resource shortage on ESX2.

Comment: @user2798081 Exactly, you don’t migrate them if you dont have enough ressource in target. VMWare dont have script to close a VM to allow another’s one to come in.